# Why is a range of a function commonly designated as E(x)?

Tags: terminology

Why is a range of a function commonly designated as E(x)?
I can understand that domain of a function is written as D(x), but I could not find similar reason about range. If it is derived from latin, could you name the original term?

Comment: Is that standard?  Don't think I've seen it...seems like terrible notation as the range (and domain) obviously depend on $f$, not on $x$ in any way.  Can you give some links to where it is used?

Comment: I have never seen this "common designation". Can you edit the question to post at least one example, with surrounding text and a reference? I've seen $D$ for domain, but never $D(x)$. Where did you see that?

Comment: Like others commenting, I’ve never seen particular notation like this used for domain and range of a function, so I’ll just guess that someone thought to use $E$ because it’s the letter that comes after $D$. But as noted, $D(x)$ is rather awful notation for the domain of $f$, because the domain of $f$ is not a function and $D(x)$ looks like a function.

Comment: I agree with the above comments; no "standard" symbols for [Domain and Range](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_of_a_function#Formal_definition).

Comment: Sometimes, when reading a textbook, the student assumes the notation particular to that book are "standard" notations used also elsewhere.

Comment: Maybe useful [Exactly who popularized the modern definition of domain and codomain of functions?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/719227/exactly-who-popularized-the-modern-definition-of-domain-and-codomain-of-function)

Comment: Sorry, it sertainly was E(f). In all russian books this letter is used and i try to understand why.